# A Simple Form: Php & Html

Tags: php, html, forms

I-m writing a simple form in HTML that submits the user name and age, then opens a `.php` page and prints them.

This is the code:

**main.html**

```
<form action="Test.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="fname" />
    Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Test.php**

```html
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["fname"]; ?>!<br />
You are <?php echo $_POST["age"]; ?> years old.
```

Тhe problem is, when I open the `main.html`, enter some values and press `Submit`, it doesnt show me the `Test.php` page, instead it downloads it.

Аny suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the server support php at all?

Comment: Php not configured properly for your server

Comment: @DmitryTeplyakov, How can I configure it properly?

Comment: Are you requesting the page via localhost/127.0.0.1 or just opening the file in the browser?

Comment: Try adding a [test PHP script](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) to your web server dir, and make sure PHP is actually installed/enabled. `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` - user1027562

Comment: @lovedager, Im requesting it via localhost. Should I do something else?

Comment: @Truth, How would I do it? Thanks!

Comment: @HowaidaKhoureieh Make a new file, type `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, save it as PHP and open it.

Answer (score 1):

Check your server is running.
Check you request page properly (http://localhost/main.html or over your virtual host)

XAMPP should be configure server properly.
Most common things for php work in httpd.conf are:

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so # or necessary .dll for windows
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Restart apache and try again.
Try to directly request Test.php, you should see some warnings if all is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Restart Apache or whatever your webserver may be.

`sudo service apache2 restart` in Ubuntu, or use the XAMPP control panel.

Then try again.